# How to print one character at a time on one line?

Tags: python

How would one print the string "hello world" onto one line, but one character at a time so that there is a delay between the printing of each letter? My solutions have either resulted in one character per line, or a delayed printing of the entire string at once. This is the closest I've gotten.

```
import time
string = 'hello world'
for char in string:
    print char
    time.sleep(.25)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Two tricks here, you need to use a stream to get everything in the right place and you also need to flush the stream buffer.

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.25)

delay_print("hello world")
```

Comment: Why the string interpolation? `sys.stdout.write(c)` works just fine on my system.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a simple trick for Python 3, since you can specify the `end` parameter of the `print` function:

```
>>> import time
>>> string = "hello world"
>>> for char in string:
    print(char, end='')
    time.sleep(.25)


hello world
```

Have fun! The results are animated now!

Comment: Is there a reason not to use this solution?  It seems simple and elegant.

Comment: A tiny one. The default output is buffered, so what you want is to add flush=True like so: `print(char, end='', flush=True)`

Answer (score 5):

```
import sys
import time

string = 'hello world\n'
for char in string:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came with different solution. **Flushing buffer did not help**. OS: Windows 10, python 3.7.4 64-bit

**not working code**

```
[while loop]
    [if statement]
       try:               
            playsound(path)              
            time.sleep(60)
```

**working code**

```
import time
from time import sleep
[while loop]
    [if statement]
       try:               
            playsound(path)              
            sleep(60)
```