# how to print out single character at random intervals in python?

Tags: python, string, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print one character at a time on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246076/how-to-print-one-character-at-a-time-on-one-line)

I'm trying to print out characters at small random intervals to make it look like it's "typed" onto the screen.

```
large_string = """line1
                  line2
                  line3
               """
for i in range (0, len(large_string)):
    sys.stdout.write(large_string[i])
    sleep(random.random())
```

My issue is that it prints waits a little, then prints out the whole line rather than printing out character by character. What am I missing here?

Comment: See the accepted answer to the other question.

Comment: Thanks, guess I didn't search hard enough.