# How can i print string one by character without space between them IN python2.7?

Tags: python, string, slice

When I print a strings character one by one in a line, space occur automatic. between them!!

```
import time
a="mayank"
for z in a:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print z,
```

> > m a y a n k

But I want to print them without spaces between them!!
Like:-

> > mayank

In python2.7

Comment: use `end` argument with print, say :
`print(z, end='')`. I assume you are using `Python 3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print in Python without newline or space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print one character at a time on one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246076/how-to-print-one-character-at-a-time-on-one-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(z, end='')
```

Another option:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(z)
```

If your Python is running with buffered io, you might not see any output until a newline character is written.  In that case, you can force writing the output immediately by adding a call to `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import time
a="mayank"
for z in a:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print (z, end="")
```